# AlertManager notification from cAdvisor container

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager, cadvisor

I am using the common monitoring tools (Prometheus, cAdvisor, AlertManager), and I faced this issue that one of the servers firing each 30min `containerCpuUsage` but unfortunately I do not know which container is this (*I am guessing this is the cAdvisor itself, but the cpu usage is really low on it*!!) so my first question is, is there any way to tell AlertManager - base on prometheus rules - to send also the container name?

(cAdvisor itself using more CPU than the other containers)

cadvisor-rule.yaml

```
- alert: ContainerCpuUsage
    expr: (sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[3m])) BY (instance, name) * 100) > 80
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: "Container CPU usage (instance {{ $labels.instance }})"
      description: "Container CPU usage is above 80%\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}"
```

I've tried `{{ $labels.name }}` and `{{ $labels.job }}` but not working.

so let's call the instance name is A and then there is a nginx & cadvisor container inside it. Monitoring tools are running on the other instance, how can I get container names into rules labels or if there is other way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

In cAdvisor it is stated that the container itself can take a bit more CPU sometimes.

```
  # cAdvisor can sometimes consume a lot of CPU, so this alert will fire constantly.
  # If you want to exclude it from this alert, exclude the serie having an empty name: container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name!=""}
```

In my case, I started the cAdvisor container with `--name=cadvisor` and added following as a rule expression:

```
expr: (sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name!="cadvisor"}[3m])) BY (instance, name) * 100) > 80
```